# Inject ListProduct not working on M2.2

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.2, product-list

I have codes below to get the products listed on Category page:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Category extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_listProduct;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $product_list,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_listProduct = $product_list;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getProducts(){
        $products = $this->_listProduct->getLoadedProductCollection();
        $result = [];
        foreach ($products as $product){
            $result[] = $product->getSku();
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

The function `getProducts()` **does work** and show product SKUs correctly on Magento 2.1. But on my testing Magento 2.2.2 site it breaks with the following error message:

```
    1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (OutOfBoundsException): No element found with ID ''.

Exception #0 (OutOfBoundsException): No element found with ID ''.
#0 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php(603): Magento\Framework\Data\Structure->_assertElementExists(NULL)
#1 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php(319): Magento\Framework\Data\Structure->_insertChild(NULL, '0.51306900 1526...', NULL, 'toolbar')
#2 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(394): Magento\Framework\Data\Structure->setAsChild('0.51306900 1526...', NULL, 'toolbar')
#3 /path/to/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(115): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->setChild(NULL, '0.51306900 1526...', 'toolbar')
#4 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(371): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->setChild(NULL, '0.51306900 1526...', 'toolbar')
#5 /path/to/magento/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php(713): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->setChild('toolbar', '0.51306900 1526...')
#6 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php(433): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->setChild('toolbar', Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar))
#7 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php(391): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->configureToolbar(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar), Object(Magento\CatalogStaging\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor))
#8 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php(107): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->initializeProductCollection()
#9 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php(130): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->_getProductCollection()
#10 /path/to/magento/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->getLoadedProductCollection()
#11 /path/to/magento/app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Category.php(41): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->getLoadedProductCollection()
#12 /path/to/magento/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/category/head.phtml(11): Cleargo\AppierCode\Block\Category->getProducts()
#13 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/vendor/d...')
#14 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Cleargo\AppierCode\Block\Category), '/home/vendor/d...', Array)
#15 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/vendor/d...')
#16 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#17 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#18 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('appier_category')
#19 /path/to/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('appier_category')
#20 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('appier_category')
#21 /path/to/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('appier_category', true)
#22 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(511): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('appier_category', true)
#23 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/container.phtml(10): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml()
#24 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/vendor/d...')
#25 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template), '/home/vendor/d...', Array)
#26 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/vendor/d...')
#27 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#28 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(250): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#29 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#30 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#31 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#32 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#33 /path/to/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#34 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#35 /path/to/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#36 /path/to/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#37 /path/to/magento/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#38 {main}
```

What's wrong with my codes? Thanks.

Comment: You did the wrong code , Injection of  a block class with other block is not good idea .

Comment: did you find any solution, here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because inside `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php:391` call `configureToolbar()` method to set **toolbar** for `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` class.

However, `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` doesn't exist in current layout => Failed to try `$this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);` at line 433.

You'd better write your own code to avoid core errors.